# How to fit mathematical formula with neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I would like to fit a pytorch feed forward network on a crafted dataset with dependency between labels y and two features from the dataset.

Dataset is generated using `np.random.random_sample` for a distribution between 0 and 1 and label is computed using the two functions below:

- `sum_bin_label`
- `sum_mod_label`

The first function I can see that both training and validation loss of the neural network is decreasing and eventually it is able to approximate the function with close to 100%, what is expected, but for the second function that is using `sum` and `modulo(num_classes)` it is unable to make any progress. I have tried multiple learning rates and network architectures but did not manage to fit it.

I am interested to see how that function can be fitted.

Bellow is a simple example that can be pasted directly to a jupyter notebook or any kind of python repl for that matter.

Thanks in advance!

Imports

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import torch.utils.data as utils
DATASHAPE = (2000, 2)
NUM_CLASSES = 3
```

Functions and classes used

```
def sum_mod_label(x):
    return np.array([x for x in map(
        lambda x: x % NUM_CLASSES, map(int, (x[:, 0] + x[:, 1]) * 100))])

def sum_bin_label(x):
    def binit(x):
        if x < 0.807:
            return 0
        if x < 1.169:
            return 1
        return 2

    return np.array(
        [x for x in map(lambda x: binit(x), x[:, 0] + x[:, 1])])

class RandomModuloDataset(utils.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, shape, label_fn):
        self.data = np.random.random_sample(shape)
        self.label = label_fn(self.data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx, :], self.label[idx]

class FeedForward(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=-1)

        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(
            self.input_size, self.input_size)

        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(
            self.input_size, self.num_classes)

    def forward(self, x, **kwargs):
        output = self.fc2(self.relu(self.fc1(x.float())))
        return self.softmax(output)

def fitit(trainloader, epochs=10):
    neurons = DATASHAPE[1]

    net = FeedForward(neurons, NUM_CLASSES)
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            inputs, labels = data

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        print('[%d] loss: %.3f' %
              (epoch + 1, loss.item()))
```

Iteration with first function (eventually converges)

```
sum_bin_tloader = utils.DataLoader(
    RandomModuloDataset(DATASHAPE, sum_bin_label))
fitit(sum_bin_tloader, epochs=50)

[1] loss: 1.111
[2] loss: 1.133
[3] loss: 1.212
[4] loss: 1.264
[5] loss: 1.261
[6] loss: 1.199
[7] loss: 1.094
[8] loss: 1.011
[9] loss: 0.958
[10] loss: 0.922
[11] loss: 0.896
[12] loss: 0.876
[13] loss: 0.858
[14] loss: 0.844
[15] loss: 0.831
[16] loss: 0.820
[17] loss: 0.811
[18] loss: 0.803
[19] loss: 0.795
[20] loss: 0.788
[21] loss: 0.782
[22] loss: 0.776
[23] loss: 0.771
[24] loss: 0.766
[25] loss: 0.761
[26] loss: 0.757
[27] loss: 0.753
[28] loss: 0.749
[29] loss: 0.745
[30] loss: 0.741
[31] loss: 0.738
[32] loss: 0.734
[33] loss: 0.731
[34] loss: 0.728
[35] loss: 0.725
[36] loss: 0.722
[37] loss: 0.719
[38] loss: 0.717
[39] loss: 0.714
[40] loss: 0.712
[41] loss: 0.709
[42] loss: 0.707
[43] loss: 0.705
[44] loss: 0.703
[45] loss: 0.701
[46] loss: 0.699
[47] loss: 0.697
[48] loss: 0.695
[49] loss: 0.693
[50] loss: 0.691
```

Iteration with second function (does not converge)

```
sum_mod_tloader = utils.DataLoader(
    RandomModuloDataset(DATASHAPE, sum_mod_label))
fitit(sum_mod_tloader, epochs=50)

[1] loss: 1.059
[2] loss: 1.065
[3] loss: 1.079
[4] loss: 1.087
[5] loss: 1.091
[6] loss: 1.092
[7] loss: 1.092
[8] loss: 1.092
[9] loss: 1.092
[10] loss: 1.091
[11] loss: 1.091
[12] loss: 1.091
[13] loss: 1.091
[14] loss: 1.091
[15] loss: 1.090
[16] loss: 1.090
[17] loss: 1.090
[18] loss: 1.090
[19] loss: 1.090
[20] loss: 1.090
[21] loss: 1.090
[22] loss: 1.089
[23] loss: 1.089
[24] loss: 1.089
[25] loss: 1.089
[26] loss: 1.089
[27] loss: 1.089
[28] loss: 1.089
[29] loss: 1.089
[30] loss: 1.089
[31] loss: 1.089
[32] loss: 1.089
[33] loss: 1.089
[34] loss: 1.089
[35] loss: 1.089
[36] loss: 1.089
[37] loss: 1.089
[38] loss: 1.089
[39] loss: 1.089
[40] loss: 1.089
[41] loss: 1.089
[42] loss: 1.089
[43] loss: 1.089
[44] loss: 1.089
[45] loss: 1.089
[46] loss: 1.089
[47] loss: 1.089
[48] loss: 1.089
[49] loss: 1.089
[50] loss: 1.089
```

I expect to be able to fit both functions, since NN should be able to find any function y=f(x) describing the dependend variable, but the training is not progressing for sum_mod_label.

Using catboost I was able to get reasonable accuracy (~75% on the sum_mod_label)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to plot your data and you will see that functions produce datasets of different complexities.
In the second case classes are almost inseparable, so you need to increase your model complexity.

How to increase your model complexity:

- More layers
- More hidden units
- Tweak batch size
- Tweak lr, try to use lr-scheduler
- Try another optimizer, for example Adam
- To avoid overfitting in very deep networks add dropout layers
- Take a look at very promising [Self Normalizing Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02515)

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

DATASHAPE = (2000, 2)
NUM_CLASSES = 3


def sum_mod_label(x):
    return np.array([x for x in map(lambda x: x % NUM_CLASSES, map(int, (x[:, 0] + x[:, 1]) * 100))])


def sum_bin_label(x):
    def binit(x):
        if x < 0.807:
            return 0
        if x < 1.169:
            return 1
        return 2

    return np.array([x for x in map(lambda x: binit(x), x[:, 0] + x[:, 1])])

data = np.random.random_sample(DATASHAPE)
bin_label = sum_bin_label(data)
mod_label = sum_mod_label(data)


def plot_data(data, label, title):
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.scatter(data[..., 0], data[..., 1], c=label)
    plt.show()

plot_data(data, bin_label, 'sum_bin_label')
plot_data(data, mod_label, 'sum_mod_label')
```

Output:

[image: plot1]
[image: plot2]

Comment: @tsavcyn, according to universality theorem there is a neural network that can approximate every single one function. More information can be found in the following text: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html


The plots are very interesting though, but I do not believe they prove that NN cannot approximate the function. Probably if you try clustering techniques they will fail on the second example.

I am wondering what an experts have to say on that matter.

Thanks

Comment: yes, you are right according to theory you just even need one hidden layer. But "...n practice more than one hidden layers should be utilized to solve the problem faster and more efficiently..." and "..network with two hidden layers and much fewer nodes overall, should be able t os olve the same problem more efficiently.". In your case you have only 2 layers with 2 hidden units which is not enough to approximate the 2nd problem precisely. More: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/20df/e21c69abca8d32b1eb2813f2f468692e0bb2.pdf

Comment: And I am not saying that NN can't approximate it. Plot just shows that you need more complex model. More layers, hidden units, since classes are not linearly separable

Comment: So answer to your question "How to fit mathematical formula with neural network?" will be - Increase your model complexity :)

Comment: Thanks for the pdf :)

I tried with upto 10 hidden layers and 20 neurons, but still not able to converge, now that network is not able to fit the simpler function too.

Do you have any suggestion for depth/num of neurons and learning rate (is there anything else to tweak?)

Will update the question.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your prev comment. PS try to add dropout when using so much layers and hidden units

Comment: Thanks, but I am still unable to progress. Regarding the dropout it is not the issue here since it is preventing an overfit. Here we cannot even fit the network...